# React console.log not showing state array values

Tags: reactjs

In React i have a function called addOrder that adds object with parameter values to state called data.
When i try to console.log(this.state.data) i get an empty array for some reason. 
When i click button that calls addOrder function again i get array that contains objects with parameter values.
Why doesn't console.log show me array values the first time i click button?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      data:[]
    }

  }


addOrder(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
  this.setState({
    data:this.state.data.concat(
        {
         one:parameter1,
         two:parameter2,
         three:parameter3
        }
     )          
  });

  console.log(this.state.data);
}


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.addOrder('1','2','3')}>ok</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I expected console.log to show [{one: "1", two: "2", three: "3"}], but instead i got empty array []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call to **setState()** is **asynchronous** So javascript compiler does not wait for setState to finish. So it reaches the next line and print your console.log statement and since at this point of time your state is not updated and the data array is empty it prints the empty array to the console.

**setState()** also comes with a callback which executes when you state has been updated.

You can try this

```
this.setState({
data:this.state.data.concat(
    {
     one:parameter1,
     two:parameter2,
     three:parameter3
    }
 )          
}, () => console.log(this.state.data));
```

Will work fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
addOrder(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
 this.setState({
  data:this.state.data.concat(
    {
     one:parameter1,
     two:parameter2,
     three:parameter3
    }
   )          
  },()=>console.log(this.state.data));
 }
```

try this way

Answer (score 0):

**setState** is an asynchronous function. The second argument of **setState** is a callback so you can use it to know when the function has finished.